# np.vectorize of function containing dot-product

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to execute a Matrix-Vector product and adding a scalar times a constant vector. I would like to do this with four different weights on that vector, so I tried to vectorize the function. Now I get conflicting dimensions.
The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.random.rand(3,3)
d = np.random.rand(3)
Myfunc = lambda y,t: M.dot(y) + d*t
vFunc  = np.vectorize(Myfunc,excluded = ['y'])

y_0 = np.array([1,1,1])
c   = np.array([0.5,1,1.5])
print(vFunc(y_0,c))
```

Now this gives me an Error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,)
```

And I don't know why. As far as I understood, it should give me three seperate results.

The expected result would be like this:
if I call the function with c being a scalar, I should just get one vector as a result:

```
M.dot(y) + d*scalar
```

If I call it with c being a vector of three elements, I want a list of three vectors as results:

```
M.dot(y) + d*c1
M.dot(y) + d*c2
M.dot(y) + d*c3
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @coldspeed I edited the question!

Comment: [That's not the error I'm seeing.](https://ideone.com/DQUZxT)

Comment: Why didn't you do a simple iteration, `[Myfunc(y_0, i) for i in c]`?  It's easier to see what's going on,   and not any slower.

Comment: Using `np.vectorize` is NOT `vectorization`.  It's a misleading name.  If you set the `otypes=['O']`, you'll see that it produces a 3x3 array for each element of `c`.  Without that `vectorize` expects your function to return a scalar for each element of `c`.  Once you step away from simple scalar functions, `np.vectorize` is hard to use correctly, and it never gives us any speedup.

Comment: Your use of `excluded=['y']` is wrong.  `y` isn't a keyword argument.  `excluded=[0]` is correct.  That's another way in which `vectorize` is tricky to use.

Comment: @hpaulj Your two comments fixed it! I had no idea vectorize is so tricky to use. If you'd like you could write them as a short answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`M.dot(y_0) + d*c` should give you the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant to the follwing:

```
In [103]: M = np.arange(9).reshape([3, 3])

In [104]: y = np.arange(3)

In [105]: c = np.arange(3) + 1

In [106]: d = 4

In [107]: M @ y + (d * c)[:, None]
Out[107]:
array([[ 9, 18, 27],
       [13, 22, 31],
       [17, 26, 35]])
```